# DBAccess v1.6.2 initWithPrimaryKeyValue returns nil

Tags: ios, dbaccess

I'm trying to init entity with id.

```
User *user = [[User alloc] initWithPrimaryKeyValue:userID];
```

And it always returns nil, if there is no entity in database with this ID. But documentations says it should return a new object with userID primary key. What's wrong?

Comment: It does not work. I also tried. Should be a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for finding/pointing out the bug.  This has now been fixed in version 1.06.4, which can be downloaded here.

http://www.db-access.org/downloads

Our automated testing only seemed to test existing objects, so we have now expanded to include all aspects of retrieving and also a full persistence lifecycle for those objects.

We have also added a method,

```
+ (id)objectWithPrimaryKeyValue:(NSObject*)priKeyValue;
```

Which works exactly as the buggy version of init did, just in case anyone wants that kind of feature.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

You can always email [devs@db-access.org](http://mailto:devs@db-access.org) to report bugs or suggest enhancements if it is quicker for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Adrian, I really like to use your framework. It would be great if you also update version in cocoapods.